# how to use Python3.3 access online MySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql

I am new to python and network programming.
Recently I am having trouble accessing my online database.

The problem is that I want to write a code and execute it on my computer to acces my online data base, and the only thing I want to do is to access the informaion in my database and do some change.
The first question is that I don't know what to use as parameters.

here is what show up on my online database, which I can access using internet browser:

```
173.201.136.195

Server version: 5.0.96-log
Server: 173.201.136.195 via TCP/IP
User: user123123@72.167.233.37
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

I don't understand which ip should I use when i connect to it, `'173.201.136.195' or '173.201.136.195'` and which username should I use. `'user123123' or 'user123123@72.167.233.37'`

This is the code I use:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='173.201.136.195',user='user123123',passwd="123123123",db='TestData')
```

phthon shell shows that:

```
File "F:\Program Files\Python33\lib\pymysql\connections.py", line 819, in _connect 2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on %r (%s)" % (self.host, e))
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on    \'173.201.136.195\' ((1045, "Access denied for user \'user123123\'@\'142.151.201.116\'   (using password: YES)"))')
```

What on earth is `142.151.201.116` ?

Comment: try user='user123123@72.167.233.37'

Comment: I just tried My SQL query browser and it works fine with my username and password. But when I try it on Python shell, it failed. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

the error means that access to the server `173.201.136.195` is denied to the user `user123123` at ip `142.151.201.116`. When you give access to a user on mysql database you specify the ip or wildcads for multiple ips. So access to the database for user is per ip.

example:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

will give access to username on **all hosts**. but this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'10.20.30.40' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

will give access to username at **ip 10.20.30.40**

this information is on `mysql.user` table